# Given a string inside a nested Json, how can I change its id given a specific string?

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I am reading a Json which is a list of several dictionaries like this:

```
a_list = [ {
    "ID": "20394820938",
    "data": [
      {
        "fruit": "tomato",
        "provider": "walmart",
        "availability": "True",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " orange ",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "watermelon",
        "provider": "destination",
        "availability": "cotsco",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " the watermelon is new",
        "Type": false
      }
    ],
    "API": false,
    "count": 0
  },  
  {
    "ID": "203948lHBFNPO",
    "data": [
      {
        "fruit": "apple",
        "provider": "walmart",
        "availability": "True",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " this is a tomato ",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "lemon",
        "provider": "unknown",
        "availability": "cotsco",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " orange ",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "banana",
        "provider": "unknown",
        "availability": "unknown",
        "Type": false
      }
    ],
    "API": false,
  }
]
```

How can I attach `IM00N` to the id value of the Json if and only if the dictionary has the string `apple` in one of its subelements? For instance:

```
a_list = [ {
    "ID": "20394820938",
    "data": [
      {
        "fruit": "tomato",
        "provider": "walmart",
        "availability": "True",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "apple",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "watermelon",
        "provider": "destination",
        "availability": "cotsco",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " the watermelon is new",
        "Type": false
      }
    ],
    "API": false,
    "count": 0
  },  
  {
    "ID": "IM00N-203948lHBFNPO",
    "data": [
      {
        "fruit": "apple",
        "provider": "walmart",
        "availability": "True",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " this is a tomato ",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "lemon",
        "provider": "unknown",
        "availability": "cotsco",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " orange ",
        "Type": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "banana",
        "provider": "unknown",
        "availability": "unknown",
        "Type": false
      }
    ],
    "API": false,
  }
]
```

I tried to build a regular expression but its difficult because there is no pattern in the elements of each sub-dictionary inside the list. What is the correct way to approach this matching and replacing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify the data with a for loop:

```
for entry in a_list:
    if any('apple' in item['fruit'] for item in entry['data']):
        entry['ID'] = 'IM00N-' + entry['ID']
```

If the shape of your data varies, so that some entries don't have the `fruit` key, you can catch `KeyError` or use `dict.get`

```
for entry in a_list:
    if any('apple' in item.get('fruit', '') for item in entry.get('data', [])):
        entry['ID'] = 'IM00N-' + entry['ID']
```

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can use the `in` operator with strings.

Comment: could you show the try catch modification? Thanks for the help!

Comment: In a generator expression, you can't use `try`, but you can use `dict.get` with a default value instead.